# T SQL Script to loop all user databases and select count of all(*) from three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a script in T-SQL to loop all user databases and select count of all(*) from three tables, where count condition is > 2, if that satisfies an email should be triggered.

I tried this but I am sure that I am doing some huge mistake. I am very new to scripting, please help.

I have tried it by using :

```
DECLARE @TableRowCounts TABLE (
    [databaseNAme] Varchar(100), 
    [RowCount] INT
);

INSERT INTO @TableRowCounts ([databaseNAme], [RowCount])
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'select ''?'' as database_name,use ''?'' select count(*) TABLE_XYZ' ;

Select * From @TableRowCounts
```

And this:

```
DECLARE @TableRowCounts TABLE (
    [databaseNAme] Varchar(100),
    [TableName] VARCHAR(128), 
    [RowCount] INT
);

INSERT INTO @TableRowCounts ([databaseNAme],[TableName], [RowCount])
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'select ''?'' as database_name,o.name,max(i.rowcnt )
                      From sys.objects o 
                    inner join sys.sysindexes i on o.object_id=i.id 
                    where o.type=''U'' and o.name =''tableXYZ'' 
                    group by o.name' ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way, for 3 tables existing in every database

`EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?]; select ''?'' as database_name,  (select count(*) as cnt from Table_XYZ) + (select count(*) as cnt from Table_PQR) + (select count(*) as cnt from Table_ABC) as cnt'` ;

If you need separate count for every table

`EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?]; select ''?'' as database_name, ''Table_XYZ'' as tableName, count(*) as cnt from Table_XYZ union select  ''?'' , ''Table_PQR'', count(*) from Table_PQR union select ''?'' , ''Table_ABC'' , count(*)  from Table_ABC;'`

Comment: This one worked, i will figure out a way to display table name in result and store that result in a temp table

Comment: Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: Can't see the problem. Tested on my DB replacing table names OK

Comment: Thank you serg..! with your help have been able to accomplish my task. 

CREATE TABLE #xyz
(
            DbName NVARCHAR(255)
            ,tableName NVARCHAR(255)
            ,COUNT NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #XYZ
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'IF ''?''  like ''%_DB_%''
BEGIN
       use [?]; select ''?'' as database_name, ''COLOUMN'' as tableName, 
count(*) as COUNT from TABLE1 WHERE DeLETED =''N''   union select  ''?'' , 
''COLOUMN 2'', count(*) from TABLE 2 WHERE DeLETED =''N'';
END'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @TableRowCounts TABLE
 ([databaseNAme] Varchar(100), 
 [RowCount] INT) ;

  INSERT INTO @TableRowCounts ([databaseNAme], [RowCount]) 
  EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'use ?; select ''?'',count(*) TABLE_XYZ' ;
```

Comment: Thank you, but strangely i am getting result as 1